# Performance when make Pagination on category with losts of records

Tags: mysql, sorting, optimization

I have one big category with lots of records.
and i have to sort it topic_lastpost_time

but mysql is seem so slow when i do it.
it took 3 seconds to complete query
i indexed topic_lastpost_time field

Here's the example. How can i spped up it?

```
# Query_time: 3  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 36075
SELECT   t.topic_id,
         t.m_id,
         t.m_username, 
         t.topic_title,
         t.topic_lastpost_time
FROM     p_topics t
WHERE    t.fc_id = '21'
         AND t.topic_state = '1'
ORDER BY t.topic_type DESC, 
         t.topic_lastpost_time DESC 
LIMIT    0,50;
```

Comment: Are `fc_id` and `topic_state` also indexed?

Comment: It might be a missing index on `fc_id` and `topic_state`. Please post the result of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE p_topics` in order to verify that.

Comment: yes, fc_id, topic_state already indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of order by clause

```
SELECT   t.topic_id,
     t.m_id,
     t.m_username, 
     t.topic_title,
     t.topic_lastpost_time
FROM     p_topics t
WHERE    t.fc_id = '21'
     AND t.topic_state = '1'
ORDER BY t.topic_lastpost_time DESC  ,
t.topic_type DESC
LIMIT    0,50;
```

Comment: i need priority for topic_type, because i need most important topic on the top positions.